# How can I trim /page/ URL with PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php

Let me explain the situation to the best of my abilities. I'm using "?orderby=date&order=ASC" and "?orderby=date&order=DESC" which works fine.

If the user is in domain.com/category/page/2 and clicks another "orderby" button; it doesn't reset the URL and keeps the /page/2. The problem here is, when the user clicks these, I want the URL to reset to the core. Which is domain.com/category/. I want to trim the URL (page and number) so when the user clicks on another orderby, the URL is reset and a new orderby is begun from scratch. I don't want it to keep the /page/2/ or /3/ slug.

So the page & number should be trimmed each time the orderby button is pressed.

Comment: What orderby button? Did you add this button? Is the button part of a form?

Comment: I've put a drop down menu to filter my posts in my category.

Comment: How? You’ll need to share code.

Comment: Check 'Sırala' dropdown on this page: https://www.mgc.com.tr/yayinlar/

Comment: `<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="?orderby=date&order=DESC" class="nav-link dropdown-item" type="button" role="tab">Yeniden Eskiye</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="?orderby=date&order=ASC" class="nav-link dropdown-item" type="button" role="tab">Eskiden Yeniye</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="?orderby=title&order=ASC" class="nav-link dropdown-item" type="button" role="tab">A'dan Z'ye</a></li>`

Comment: Can anyone help?